# superclass mismatch for class Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When i create a new ruby app i recive this error

```
rails aborted!
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Command
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:2:in `<class:Thor>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:1:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
```

Answer (score 2):

in Ubuntu just run these two commands that solves this problem.

- dpkg -r --force-depends  ruby-thor
- gem install thor

Comment: I think you forgot to mark this as the answer